# Acoustic characteristics of thoracic diaphragm

Tags: image-processing, acoustics, ultrasound

I am looking for any kind of information about the acoustic characteristics of the thoracic diaphragm. In particular, I'm looking for characteristics which will allow to differentiate it from other muscles using ultrasound, MRI, CT, etc.

References to the literature are especially welcome.